# How to query records by aggregate conditions on association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Order
  belongs_to :guest
  has_many :line_items, inverse_of: :order
  has_many :tickets, through: :line_items
end

class Ticket
  belongs_to :guest
  belongs_to :line_item
end
```

I want to create a `scope` on `Order` that would let me query orders that have more than 1 ticket belonging to the `order's` `Guest`. An example: I place an order for 3 tickets, then the scope would return that order. If I placed the same order, then transferred 2 tickets to a different `Guest`, then I would no longer match the `scope` because the `count` of tickets where `tickets.guest_id = orders.guest_id` is only 1 (out of 3 total).

I've tried something like:

```
scope :has_untransferred_tickets, -> { joins(:tickets).having('count(tickets.guest_id = orders.guest_id) > 1') }
```

But no dice. I'm on Postgres. Thanks for any help. It's important that its a `scope` so it returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Orders` that I can chain.

Answer (score 0):

Move the tickets and orders guest comparison to a where clause, then perform the count on the total number of tickets returned.

```
scope :has_untransferred_tickets, -> { joins(:tickets).where('tickets.guest_id = orders.guest_id').having('count(tickets.id) > 1') }
```

Comment: This is progress, however now I get: "PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "orders.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function". If I add the .group('orders.id') then the result is a hash like {"*order_id*" => 1}. How do I get this to work and return the ActiveRecord::Relation of orders?

Comment: This works:   scope :has_untransferred_tickets, -> { where(id: joins(:tickets).group('orders.id').where('tickets.guest_id = orders.guest_id').having('count(tickets.id) > 1').count.keys) } .... but feels pretty hacky.